# Can't login with curl

Tags: php, curl, authentication, hidden, field

I've got a question about curl, i've searched everywhere en tried many things, but i can't login. I try to login to a page. I think it has something to do with the hidden fields, the hidden fields are not random generated.

I'm familiar with the basics of php, but not a expert. If you comment on this question could you maybe write some comments with it, i really want te learn!

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$url = 'see url above';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>',print_r($info),'</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: you have `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);` twice

Comment: I think i got it wrong when i copied my code here, it isn't there in my original code. Changed it in the example, thanks!

Comment: What makes you think you cannot login? What behaviour are you getting that is undesirable?

Comment: When i look in my array, the HTTP_CODE always returns 200. Dont' matter if i pass a wrong password.

Comment: Did you try to login by the browser? Perhaps the server is not set up correctly?

Comment: I had posted this before... as an answer (meant to be a comment) Change `CURLAUTH_BASIC` to `CURLAUTH_ANY`... And no, you shouldn't use `CURLAUTH_ANY` if it's unnecessary. I just wanted you to try it to see if ANY methods would work. It sounds like a server config error or something to that effect...

Comment: @FrankSmith .. Forget about my base64 attempt. It is correct for plain HTTP. But the curl extension will do it for you. So don't use `base64_encode()`. Sorry, I was wrong

Comment: Thanks for the advice brcoding, no problem hek2mgl!

Comment: @nalply What do you mean by login by the browser? I can login with my credentials on the website. But not from a remote website.

Comment: It's for checking whether login will work at all. If it doesn't work with the browser you know that there's a problem with the server or with the connection to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you do not need basic auth.
As I can see there are simple form and hidden vars in the page.
Try to send them via POST.

Something like this:

```
$url =  'http://www.cibap.nl/index.php';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$post_data = array(
'ACT'       => '9',
'RET'       => '/login',
'site_id'   => '1',
'username'  => $username,
'password'  => $password,
'autologin' => '1'  
);

$ch = curl_init($url);

$postargs = http_build_query($post_data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postargs);

//Use cookie file if needed (probably needed)
//$cookiefile = '/path/to/cookie.txt'; 
//any filename, curl stores and reads this file next time
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile); 

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);   
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>',print_r($output),'</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm a bit further right now. I've a small redirect message with, your logged in right now, click this link to continue to the website. And it redirect to the $url. But if I check my $output, i still get a http_code 200.

I've tried setting returntransfer and followloaction to false. And if i run this check, I see that my httpCode is still 200.

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($httpCode == 200){
     header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
}else{
     echo 'not logged in';
}

Comment: What is your current question? Is there something unexpected (after the POST)? What is login for, why do you try to login there? If you try to download (as example) something protected by auth form, you have to use cookie and than do another request to get what you want. Anyway if something additional needed to POST, you may use Chrome browser with ctrl+shift+j (click network)and inspect packets to the server and than fix your php request.

Comment: Hey Andrey,

On the website I get a redirect, it shows a message "Welcome, you're now logged in" and after 5 seconds it returns to cibap.nl. I would like to use the coockie to get the schedule of each person, that the reason why to need to login. Because the schedules are not accesible without a login.

Comment: Still not clear for me. Why shouldn't it be 200? You make request and get an output. If HTML source contain a code (javascript or meta refresh tag) it does not mean it is a redirect. When you logged in first time you have a cookie. Does not matter where you are redirected by the browser. You have a cookie, using it go where you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i think i can fix it now. I'll keep you up-to-date! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that you are logged in by looking at the cookies that are returned. The application appears to always return HTTP code 200 whether you put in bogus information or not.

Comment: I've set it up with coockies and my http code changes to 302, but it doesn't matter what credentials i pass, it always returns that code.

Comment: The coockie is written on my remote website, so it's writible.

Comment: 302 means that the server is trying to forward you to a new url location. You should enable the ability to follow 302's in your curl header.

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to give that a try